# What does this snippet mean?

Tags: html, drupal

It's what I see in `page.tpl.php` of Drupal,but I don't understand.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><?php /* Needed to avoid Flash of Unstyle Content in IE */ ?> </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go: [Flash of Unstyled Content or FOUC](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/)

It actually does not refer to Adobe Flash, it's referring to rendering of html before applying css to it. This is a hack to prevent IE from rendering html before applying css to it.